# Repaint() doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Somehow repaint doesn't work when I try to call it. It doesn't give an error, it looks like it just ignores the whole function.

Here is my code:

```
public class Neerslag extends JComponent {
JPanel painting = new JPanel();
private int j = 0;

  Neerslag() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(370, 200));
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

    g.fillOval(j, 20, 100, 20);
    g.fillOval(j + 10, 30, 100, 20);
    System.out.println("test2");

  }

  public void move(int j) {
    System.out.println("test");
    if (j < 50) {
        j++;
    } else {
        j = -j;
    }
    /*try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("sleep exception");
    }*/
    this.repaint();
  }

  public JPanel showPaint() {
    painting.add(new Neerslag());
    return painting;
  }

  public void Clear() {
    painting.repaint();
    System.out.println("hello");
  }
}
```

and

```
public class NeerslagFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
NeerslagPanel panel1 = new NeerslagPanel();;
private int i=0;
Neerslag neerslag = new Neerslag();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NeerslagFrame textFieldFrame = new NeerslagFrame();
    textFieldFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    textFieldFrame.setSize(500, 350);
    textFieldFrame.setVisible(true);

}

public NeerslagFrame(){
    super ("Neerslag");
    //panel1 = 
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.add(panel1.addSideBar(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.add(panel1.addSouthBar(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(neerslag.showPaint());
}
public void Clear(){
    //Neerslag paint = new Neerslag();
    this.add(new Neerslag());
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    neerslag.move(i);
    i++;
    neerslag.repaint();
    neerslag.revalidate();
    //this.add(neerslag.showPaint());
}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

What have I missed? It does show the initial two ovals, but just doesn't repaint them once I changed the "j" value.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you adding `Neerslag` into a `JPanel`?  Why not just add `Neerslag` directly?

Comment: Every time you call `showPaint`, you're creating a new instance of `Neerlsag`, when calling `neerslaf.repaint` you're repainting the `JPanel`....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repaint` isn't really what you want, what you "seem" to want is `revalidate` AND `repaint`.

Something like...

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    neerslag.move(i);
    i++;
    neerslag.revalidate();
    neerslag.repaint();
    this.add(neerslag.showPaint());
}
```

for example.

Now, for what it's worth, your design seems backwards, that is, rather than having `Neerslag` container some other container which seems to then add instance of itself to it, instead `Neerslag` should simply care only about itself and nothing else.

You should move the `painting` panel out and manage it separately, as `Neerslag` simply should not care about it - IMHO

Comment: First of all: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this solution, though it does not work. The thing is, paintcomponent does not run again. It only runs one on the start of the program. I test this with system.out.println("test2"). Looks like that is the problem. I now also changed the code a bit to what you said in the comments.

Comment: Dumps plenty of output to the console for me (try resizing the window). What version of Java and OS are you using. As I stated, you are currently repainting the panel and not the Neerslag component. Repaint is a request, the repaint manager is well within its rights to ignore it

Comment: Right, it is working for me now, somehow. Thank you!